# Ansible refactor code like reusable parameterized class or function

Tags: ansible, devops

```
roles/mysql
├── handlers
│   └── main.yml
├── tasks
│   └── main.yml
├── templates
└── vars
    └── main
        ├── mysql_user_privileges.yml
        └── mysql_users.yml
```

**var/main/mysql_user_privileges.yml**

```
---
# MySQL Admin privileges
mysql_admin_user_host: "%"
mysql_admin_user_privileges: '*.*:ALL'
mysql_admin_user_pwd: secret

# MySQL Read-only Privileges
mysql_ro_user_host: "%"
mysql_ro_user_privileges: '*.*:SELECT'
mysql_ro_user_pwd: secret
```

**mysql/tasks/main.yml**

```
---

- name: Creating MySQL READ-ONLY Users ...
  community.mysql.mysql_user:
    # login_host: "{{ mysql_login_host }}"
    login_port: "{{ mysql_login_port }}"
    login_user: "{{ mysql_login_user }}"
    login_password: "{{ mysql_login_pwd }}"
    host: "{{ mysql_ro_user_host }}"
    name: "{{ item }}"
    password: "{{ mysql_ro_user_pwd }}"
    priv: "{{ mysql_ro_user_privileges }}"
    state: present
  loop: "{{ mysql_ro_users }}"

- name: Creating MySQL ADMIN Users ...
  community.mysql.mysql_user:
    login_port: "{{ mysql_login_port }}"
    login_user: "{{ mysql_login_user }}"
    login_password: "{{ mysql_login_pwd }}"
    host: "{{ mysql_admin_user_host }}"
    name: "{{ item }}"
    password: "{{ mysql_admin_user_pwd }}"
    priv: "{{ mysql_admin_user_privileges }}"
    state: present
  loop: "{{ mysql_admin_users }}"
```

**var/main/mysql_users.yml**

```
---

# MySQL READ ONLY Users
mysql_ro_users:
  - user1


# MySQL ADMIN Users
mysql_admin_users:
  - user2
```

I'm trying Ansible for the first time. This is my code to create users on mysql server with `all` and read-only(`select`) privileges. I'm actually repeating my code in `mysql_user_privileges.yml` and `tasks/main.yml`.
I have a bit of experience with Puppet where we can use a parameterized classes and define functions to minimize the line of code and repetition but I can't find similar thing in Ansible. Can anyone refactor this in Ansible or guide me in right direction please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you want to write only one task to create all type of users?

Comment: @Frenchy - Yes, exactly, with all required options in task by passing required parameter values if not with default values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you create a parameter which is linked with the type of user:

```
- name: Creating All type of Users ...
  community.mysql.mysql_user:
    login_port: "{{ mysql_login_port }}"
    login_user: "{{ mysql_login_user }}"
    login_password: "{{ mysql_login_pwd }}"
    host: "{{ vars[item[0] + '_host'] }}"
    name: "{{ item[1] }}"
    password: "{{ vars[item[0] + '_pwd'] }}"
    priv: "{{ vars[item[0] + '_privileges'] }}"
    state: present
  loop: "{{ users  | flatten(levels=1) }}"  
  vars:
    users:
      - "{{ ['mysql_ro_user'] | product(mysql_ro_users) }}"
      - "{{ ['mysql_admin_user'] | product(mysql_admin_users) }}"
```

another way to write the tasks:

```
- name: Creating All type of Users ...
  community.mysql.mysql_user:
    # login_host: "{{ mysql_login_host }}"
    login_port: "{{ mysql_login_port }}"
    login_user: "{{ mysql_login_user }}"
    login_password: "{{ mysql_login_pwd }}"
    host: "{{ _host }}"
    name: "{{ _name }}"
    password: "{{ _pass }}"
    priv: "{{ _priv }}"
    state: present
  loop: "{{ users  | flatten(levels=1) }}" 
  vars:
    users:
      - "{{ ['mysql_ro_user'] | product(mysql_ro_users) }}"
      - "{{ ['mysql_admin_user'] | product(mysql_admin_users) }}" 
    _host: "{{ vars[item[0] + '_host'] }}"
    _pass: "{{ vars[item[0] + '_pwd'] }}"
    _priv: "{{ vars[item[0] + '_privileges'] }}"
    _name: "{{ item[1] }}"
```

---

```
_host: "{{ vars[item[0] + '_host'] }}"
```

could be written

```
_host: "{{ lookup('vars', item[0] + '_host') }}"
```

and so on....

Comment: Sir, got it. Thank you so much!. Please edit the another way of task, replacing `_pass` with `_pwd` and removing the extra `[` near items in the last line.

Comment: glad to help..yes i have fixed some errors of pasting you notice